Measuring Incompatible observables simultaneously of an entangled electron
Given that a pair of electrons are in the state $$\psi =\frac{ {|00}\rangle \pm  {|11}\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}$$ (in the the spin-$x$ eigenbasis) . If we measure the spin along $x$ axis of one of the electrons then the spin along $x$ axis for the other electron is known with certainty. If we therefore measure spin along $x$ axis of one of the electrons and simultaneously measure the spin of the other electron along $y$ axis then effectively we know both $x$ and $y$ axis spin of the electron. Is this kind of measurement possible, If yes, doesn't this violate Heisenberg's uncertainty theorem.

Can you be specific about what the computational basis is here?  I.e.,  are $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ the eigenstates of $\hat{S}_x$ or $\hat{S}_y$ or $\hat{S}_z$?

Of course you can do this.  Now you have one electron in a known eigenstate of x-spin and a different electron in a known eigenstate of y-spin.  So what?

@WillO at the time of simultaneous measurement shouldn't we know both the x and y spin value of the same electron.

"shouldn't we know both the x and y spin value of the same electron?".  What does that mean?  .   What state are you imagining the electron might be in?   There is no state in which an electron has both x and y spin values

Let $L$ and $R$ be the eigenstates of $x$-spin.  Your system is in the state $L\otimes L+R\otimes R$ $=$ $U\otimes U+D\otimes D$, where $U=L+R$ and $D=L-R$ are the eigenstates of $y$-spin.  (I am not bothering to normalize.)
Let $\phi$ be the operator corresponding to an $x$-measurement and $\psi$ be the operator corresponding to a $y$-measurement.
Your simultaneous measurements amount to an observation of the measurement $\phi\otimes\psi$.
The eigenstates of this measurement are $L\otimes U$, $L\otimes D$, $R\otimes U$ and $R\otimes D$.  Your measurement causes the state of your system to collapse into one of these unentangled states, all equiprobably in view of the equation
$$L\otimes L + R\otimes R=L\otimes U +L\otimes D+R\otimes U-R\otimes D$$
If, for example, the system is in state $L\otimes U$, you know that electron 1 is spin-left and electron 2 is spin-up.
There is nothing in quantum mechanics that prevents two unentangled electrons from having arbitrary unrelated spin states.
There is however something in quantum mechanics that prevents you from even asking the question whether a given electron might be spin-left and spin-up simultaneously.  For a single electron, there is simply no such state as "spin-left and spin-up".  Asking whether an electron could be in such a state is like asking whether an odd number can be even.  The very definition of an electron-spin state makes this impossible.
